# Mysql table composite keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have this table definition.

```
 CREATE TABLE `friendship` (
  `fID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Part1` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Part2` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AddedBy` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Accepted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`fID`),
  KEY `Part1` (`Part1`,`Part2`),
  KEY `Part1_2` (`Part1`),
  KEY `Part2` (`Part2`),
  KEY `AddedBy` (`AddedBy`),
  KEY `Accepted` (`Accepted`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Can someone explain me why key "Part1" contains Part1 and Part2, and what are good/bad side of this?
Is it better to use FK on Part1/Part2?

Is there any performance difference using this on MyISAM and InnoDB table?

Answer (score 1):

You have a bad naming convention, for one thing.  I would expect the keys to be named:

```
KEY `Part1_2` (`Part1`,`Part2`),
KEY `Part1` (`Part1`),
```

In any case, the key that has only `Part1` is not needed.  The composite key `(Part1,Part2)` can be used wherever `Part1` would be used.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain me why key "Part1" contains Part1 and Part2, and
>   what are good/bad side of this?

As far as I can tell, it's just bad naming. As far as performance and data integrity go, the name here isn't important. It *might* be troublesome if you later need to drop it by name.

Like Gordon Linoff said, the key named "Part1_2" in your question can be dropped.

> Is it better to use FK on Part1/Part2?

There are no unique constraints on either of those columns. MySQL will *still* let you reference them with a foreign key, but MySQL docs tell you not to do it. (Allowing that was a mistake; it's easier to document it than to fix it.)

*Key* in MySQL doesn't mean what it means in other SQL dbms. In *this* CREATE TABLE statement, [KEY is a synonym for INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html); it's not a synonym for UNIQUE or a shorthand for PRIMARY KEY. The only column in this table that can be safely referenced by a foreign key constraint is fID.

> Is there any performance difference using this on MyISAM and InnoDB
>   table?

InnoDB supports row-level locking, transactions, and foreign key constraints. MyISAM doesn't. I'd worry about those differences before I'd think about performance differences. It doesn't matter how fast it runs if your database gives you the wrong answers.